# Memory issues in iOS app in Unity3d at transition between scenes (made with Application.LoadLevel)

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine

I  developing an app for iOS in Unity3d.
I have memory issues with my iOS app.
There are three large peaks. Each peak is about 50 mb's.
First occurs when my app launches.
My app presents simple main menu scene (it consist of background texture and three or four GUI.buttons)
Second occurs when user taps Start button in main menu.
Third occurs when users leaves game scene.

Transition between scenes are made with Application.LoadLevel.

Before each transition i call 
Resources.UnloadUnusedAssets() and
System.GC.Collect();

App crashes ( after memory warnings) on old devices (iPad 1 and iPhone 3GS) on this transitions.

How should i debug this crashes?
Why the memory consumption ontransition between scenes is so high?
How can we reduce memory consumption in this situations?

Comment: what size is your background image? Are you using truecolor or compressed? Are you loading anything else for each scene (such as sql tables, music/sounds etc)?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try using.

```
Application.LoadLevelAdditive ("ActualSceneWhereuWantToGo");
```

Please let us know any improvements.